# How to dynamically add buttons and Silverlight player in a Grid?

Tags: silverlight, media-player, media

I'm basically trying to create the following set of code dynamically/programmatically but I'm unsure of how to do it.

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <smf:SMFPlayer x:Name="player" Grid.Row="0" AutoPlay="False">
        <smf:SMFPlayer.Playlist>
            <media:PlaylistItem 
                DeliveryMethod="AdaptiveStreaming" 
                MediaSource="http://video3.smoothhd.com.edgesuite.net/ondemand/Big%20Buck%20Bunny%20Adaptive.ism/Manifest"/>
            <media:PlaylistItem 
                DeliveryMethod="AdaptiveStreaming" 
                SelectedCaptionStreamName="textstream_eng"
                MediaSource="http://streams.smooth.vertigo.com/elephantsdream/Elephants_Dream_1024-h264-st-aac.ism/manifest"/>
        </smf:SMFPlayer.Playlist>
    </smf:SMFPlayer>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
        <Button x:Name="test1" Height="30" Width="70" Content="Test 1"/>
        <Button x:Name="test2" Height="30" Width="70" Content="Test 2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here's how it looks statically:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you must give a name to your StackPanel like this;

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spBottom" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
        <Button x:Name="test1" Height="30" Width="70" Content="Test 1"/>
        <Button x:Name="test2" Height="30" Width="70" Content="Test 2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And then, you must add the following lines in code-behind;

```
For iLoop As Integer = 0 to 4
     Dim btn As New Button With {.Content = "Button" & iLoop}
     spBottom.Children.Add(btn)
Next iLoop
```

I hope this will be help to you!

Answer (score 0):

The controls without an xmlns (XML namespace) prefix can be created in your code-behind without adding any usings. For example, in C# you can recreate the StackPanel from your XAML using the following code:

```
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal, Background = null };
panel.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 2);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(panel);
```

The elements with an xmlns prefix, anything with a colon, such as `<smf:` require knowledge of the namespace in the codebehind. The associated namespaces are defined in the first element and look like `xmlns:smf="PathToTheNamespace"`. This namespace is often refrenced in a codebehind file in C# by adding a `using PathToTheNamespace` statement at the top.

Comment: If I had a class that inherited from SMFPlayer, is there any way to specify that I want to use this child class instead of the SMFPlayer through xmlns:... ?

Comment: @Neykho, yes. You need to know the namespace path to your class that inherited from the SMFPlayer. Then either add a new xmlns or change the xlmns:smf to use the new path. i.e. `xmlns:name="clr-namespace:TypicallyThisIsNameOfYourProject.RestOfTheNamespacePath"`